# ffmpeg with libfdk_aac: AAC-HE-V2 profile doesn't work for mono sound?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming, aac, stereo

Whenever I use ffmpeg with libfdk_aac to convert a piece of audio to AAC, I noticed the `aac_he_v2` profile does not work if the source audio is mono. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i mono.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 output.m4a
```

Gives an error:

> Unable to initialize the encoder: SBR library initialization error
> Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

I can overcome this by adding the `-ac 2` option to force stereo. However it seems strange to me that this profile demands the audio to be stereo, whereas it works fine without specifying the AAC-HE-V2 profile. Maybe that's my lack of understanding how this encoder or profile works, but is it supposed to be like that?

Furthermore I assume that by specifying `-ac 2` ffmpeg will just 'fake' stereo by copying the single audio stream to an identical left and right channel?

Answer (score 0):

HE-AAC v2 is HE-AAC with Parametric Stereo - it's not meant for monaural signals.

Comment: Thanks. I did some testing on multiple mono input files, and to my surprise using `-ac 2 -profile:a aac_he_v2` always results in *smaller* output files than using `-profile:a aac_he`. Isn't that strange, or am I misunderstanding how this works? I wasn't able to detect any noticable difference in sound quality although that might require more thorough testing.

Comment: `-ac 2` will redistribute the same spectral energy, so that each channel is 1/sqrt-2 of the original sample. And since the two channels are identical, the encoder likely makes use of that.